# Custom materialui button color throwing error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

MaterialUI theme throws "decomposeColor error" in outlined buttons after modifying default secondary color.

**Button**

```
<Button variant="outlined"> Go back </Button>
```

**Error thrown**
`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'type')` at `decomposeColor`

**Code**

```
// Theme.ts > createTheme > Palette
  secondary: {
     light: '#19857b',
     dark: '#19857b',
     main: '#19857b',
     contrastText: "#19857b"
  },
```

**MUI V5.10.0**

## I tried

**1. Defining color shades **

```
{
  A100,
  A200,
  ...
}
```

**2. augmentColor tool**
`const { palette: { augmentColor } } = createTheme();`

**3. Defining color variants**

```
{
  main,
  dark,
  textContrast
}
```

Complete code here

```js
import { createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';
import { red } from '@mui/material/colors';
import "@mui/material/styles/createPalette";

declare module '@mui/material/styles' {
  interface TypographyVariants {
    heading: React.CSSProperties;
    subheading?: React.CSSProperties;
    article?: React.CSSProperties;
    caption?: React.CSSProperties;
    blockquote?: React.CSSProperties;
  }

  // allow configuration using `createTheme`
  interface TypographyVariantsOptions {
    heading?: React.CSSProperties;
    subheading?: React.CSSProperties;
    article?: React.CSSProperties;
    caption?: React.CSSProperties;
    blockquote?: React.CSSProperties;
  }
}

// Update the Typography's variant prop options
declare module '@mui/material/Typography' {
  interface TypographyPropsVariantOverrides {
    heading: true;
    subheading: true;
    h3: false;
  }
}
declare module '@mui/material/styles' {
  interface Palette {
    accent: Palette['primary'];
  }

  interface PaletteOptions {
    accent: PaletteOptions['primary'];
  }
}
declare module '@mui/material/Button' {
  interface ButtonPropsColorOverrides {
    accent: true
  }
}

const { palette: { augmentColor } } = createTheme();
const createColor = (base: string) => augmentColor({ color: { main: base } });

const theme = createTheme({
  typography: {
    fontFamily: ["Inter", 'sans-serif'].join(","),
    heading: { color: "black" },
    subheading: { color: "black" },
    article:  { color: "black" },
    caption: {},
    blockquote: { color: "black" },
  },
  palette: {
    mode: 'light',
    primary: createColor("#556cd6"),
    secondary: createColor("#19857b"),
    accent: createColor("#e5e7eb"),
    error: createColor(red.A400),
  },
  //custom theme overrides
  components: {
    MuiSkeleton: {
      defaultProps: {
        animation: "wave",
      }
    },
    MuiPaper: {
      defaultProps: {
        square: false
      }
    },
    MuiButton: {
      defaultProps: {
        variant: "contained",
        color: "secondary"
      },
    },
    MuiInputBase: {
      defaultProps: {
        size: "small"
      }
    },
    MuiFilledInput: {
      defaultProps: {
        disableUnderline: true,
      }
    },
    MuiOutlinedInput: {
      defaultProps: {
        notched: false,
      },
    },
  }
});

export default theme;
```

[Stacktrace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtK0C.png)

Comment: What's this module augmentation for with `accent`? Could you update the question with the details of what exactly are you trying to accomplish? Are you trying to add your own color in the palette and use that in a button?

Comment: @0xts oh sorry about that, it has nothing to do with the issue. i dont have any problems with custom colors, im facing a decomposeColor error with a custom value for a default color "secondary"

Comment: So, what's this override  `ButtonPropsOverrides` is supposed to do in your opinion? Excuse me, but I'm still confused because you've mentioned that this is what you tried as a solution. Could you add the complete code for your `createTheme` call?

Comment: @0xts i added the complete code snippet and corrected the question description

Comment: It seems that the problem is stemming from the usage of your `creatwColor` function. Could you also include complete stack trace?

Comment: @0xts thanks for your reply, i attached the complete stacktrace. btw the same problem occurs without the createColor function.

Comment: I'm guessing the problem comes from using `red.A400` in createColor, as the function expects a valid CSS color. Try replacing it with its actual hex: `#FF1744`

Comment: I've tried to reproduce the issue [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-poitras-4vjnxz?file=/Demo.tsx), but wasn't able to. However, [this](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/37676) issue from Github seems a bit related.